# Best way to close an entityManager

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have the following code:

```
    public Category findCategoryById(Long id) {
      EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
      try {
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          Category category = categoryDAO.findCategoryById(em, id);
          em.getTransaction().commit();
          return category;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e;
      } finally {
          em.close();
    }
  }
```

I'm handling the exceptions in my controller, but I want to make sure that entity manager is closed. I don't like that I am catching and re-throwing the error. I'm hoping to find better suggestions.

thanks

Comment: Just remove the catch.  The finally clause runs without it.

Comment: If you close/open the entityManager, you may not utilize the cache and other mechanics that the EntityManager provides. However, you may just remove the catch section within your code and place some kind exception handler on exceptions being thrown elsewhere.

Comment: If I just remove the catch, The exception will still be propagated to the calling class? with the presence of the `finally` block?

Comment: May be you can try Java8 Try-with-resource

Comment: @vegaasen: are you suggesting that I should keep `entityManager` open? should I keep one for each session?

Comment: If you down vote than please provide a comment. Thanks

Comment: What's your intention to close the entity manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to not have to care about it. If your `Entity Manager` is **container managed** (for example if you are using `ejb` or `spring` and you haven't forced a specific bean/application managed behaviour) you should let the container handle the opening/close of the transaction and in general to worry about your persistence context. It's easier, safer and, with the exclusion of very specific cases, better. The manual close of the `Entity Manager` should be directly handled by you only in case of **application managed context**, to avoid connection pool exhaustion or other problems.

Comment: After using Spring Data, I now understand